# how to split a data from database based on character

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a data april/2010 to jan/2011 
Is there any way to split the data with character to
and select the date as 
The value before "to" as FROM 
and The Value after "to" as TO
how to selet the splited value......... while i am selecting the data as it is as
 select date from mytbl 
how to select the date as two values

Comment: Please show full, complete examples of what the fields look like, and the desired results. Otherwise, it's impossible to suggest correct splitting or regex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your data in a string, like this :

```
$str = 'april/2010 to jan/2011';
```

You can use the [`explode`](http://fr.php.net/explode) function to get the two parts :

```
list ($from, $to) = explode(' to ', $str);
```

Then, just to be sure, if we echo them :

```
echo "From : $from<br />";
echo "To : $to<br />";
```

We get :

```
From : april/2010
To : jan/2011
```

Comment: @pascal Martin Thanks for your effort ....But This is like getting the result and then spliting data 
i am looking for a method which splits the data in the query itself
like < select date as from,date as To